# LINQ query where complete group meets a condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have stored a lot of text lines like this:

```
1|1000|1|0|Text Message|||
1|1000|1|1|Text Message|||
1|1000|2|0|Text Message|||
1|1000|2|1|Text Message|||
1|1000|3|0|Text Message|||
1|1001|1|0|Text Message|||
```

in a Collection: `List<ObjRow> listRows`

and this is the corresponding Class:

```
public class ObjRow
{
    private string n_Par { get; set; }
    private string n_Rad { get; set; }
    private string n_Lang { get; set; }
    private string n_Line_Mex { get; set; }
    private string text_Mex { get; set; } 
    private int n_Row { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to find which groups of lines (grouped by property `n_Rad`, 2° PIPE value) which have not the value `n_Lang == 3` (3° PIPE value).

How to do this with LINQ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Can you use better names? `ObjRow`? Why is there an `n_` before everything?

Comment: Hello, (1) yes i have tried some .GroupBy() but no one of the suggestions tried matchs my problem, how implements a conditions while grouping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be what you want:

```
var groupsWithoutLang3  = listRows
             .GroupBy(o => o.n_Rad)
             .Where(g => !g.Any(o => o.n_Lang == "3"));
```

It selects only groups without an `ObjRow` with `n_Lang == "3"`.

Comment: @Matt, no problem to give the points to Tim who also spotted Lang was a string (+he's aiming at 100K ;))

Comment: It's possible perform this query?Because with a large pack of items (about 170000) in the collection, this query return many groups wich have the propertie n_Lang == 3.

Comment: Is `n_Lang` really a string because you always show `n_Lang == 3`instead of `n_Lang == "3"` which wouldn't compile anyway. If it's a string, is it possible tthat there are white-spaces at the beginning or end? If so, you can use `String.Trim()` to remove them. An altetrnative approach (which is not really different) is using `Enumerable.All` instead of `!Any`. So `...              .Where(g => g.All(o => o.n_Lang.Trim() != "3"));`.

Comment: Yes it's string, and no, impossible it contains white-spaces. I dont know why, with a list that count 70000+ items works fine, but with a bigger list (around 170000) doesnt works.

Comment: @Matt: You might want to ask another qustion with nore details since it's difficult to help in the comments. You shouldp rovide  sample data with the failing groups if possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
var groups = listRows.GroupBy(row => row.Rad);
var result = groups.Where(group => !group.Any(item => (item.Lang == 3)));
```

This groups the rows by `Rad` and then selects the groups that do not contain a row whose `Lang` is 3.

Comment: Hi thanks for the post but this return: Can not apply operator '!' to operand of type 'lambda expression'